# Octave not producing plots in Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: octave, osx-mountain-lion

Octave is not producing any plots in Mountain Lion. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has something to do with the X11 and GNUPLOT, but it can be resolved with the following code in the Terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/lib
mv libfreetype.6.dylib libfreetype.6.dylib.bak
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib .
```

It worked for me, hope it works for you as well.

Credits to Slava at http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Mac-OS-X-Mountain-Lion-Octave-can-not-execute-sombrero-td4643502.html

Comment: even though might solve the problem, one should install Octave from a package manager (see http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X ). On the thread you mentioned, the reporter was using the App budle which has other sort of problems (aside being out of date).

Comment: This didn't work for me and I've also tried replacing DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH and it didn't work either. I've used gnuplot in my mac before, I have aquaterm and I have plotted numerous times...

Comment: @bb2 I haven't used Octave for the last 5 months or so so wouldn't know whether the context of the fix that I used might have changed.

Comment: ok thanks. For now I switched to windows, and had no problem there. Unfortunately my gnuplot in mac has stopped working =( ... Thanks.

Comment: update: gnuplot worked normally again after I re-installed Aquaterm.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I managed to fix this problem by re-installing Gnuplot via Macports. So basically what I did was the follows.

1) Install octave by downloading the binary installer from the octave website (http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X). This gets you the very latest version of octave.

2) Used macports to install GnuPlot (this will ensure that the version of GNUPlot you are running was compiled to run on OSX). I imagine this step could be performed with Homebrew as well.